# client side javascript in lotus notes client not working

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, hcl-notes

I am working on xpages project which I want to run in notes client browser not in the any othe browser because this application is not server based application , This application is kind of desktop applicationn with extension .nsf and can be run on notes clients.

In the first case I thoought it needs to hosted on server and then CSJS will work but it wont work that way also.

a simple alert("Hello World"); throws the error, 'An error occurred while updating some of the page. Not enough arguments [insIDE Window.alert] notes'

Is there any specific settings which I am missing in the applcation ?

I have tried the same in notes 10 , notes 9 , but the result is same.

Even partial refreshes workimg not expectedly .

Comment: CSJS does work in the Notes client -- make sure that you allow Javascript to be run in your Notes client Preferences.  Also, please include the code in your question, that might help.

Comment: There is no other code I have written it is just a button have onlick alert() on client side and server view.postScript('alert()') wwith some partial refresh . I open the xpage application in notes and the error I get is mentioned in the question,

Comment: where exactly there is the seetings for javascript for notes clieent?

Comment: From the menu: File, Preferences, Basic Notes Client Configuration.  Make sure Enable JavaScript is checked.  There may be other configuration options to enable.

Comment: Seeing the actual code will provide context.  What kind of button? Where is the server code?  Like that.